# Not sure on how to use the make_pipeline of sklearn correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am playing around with the titanic ddataset and trying to make a correct usage of the sklearn make_pipeline, but I'm becoming a little confused on how tu correctly build the pipelines. Here's the code:

```
def sum_relatives(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    X_copy['total_relatives'] = X_copy['SibSp'] + X_copy['Parch']
    return X_copy

class_order = [[1, 2, 3]]

ord_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    OrdinalEncoder(categories=class_order)    
    )

def age_transformer(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    for index, row in self.median_age_by_class.iterrows():
        class_value = row['Pclass']
        median_age = row['median_age']
        X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'] = X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'].fillna(median_age)
    bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    X_copy['age_interval'] = pd.cut(X_copy['Age'], bins=bins)
    return X_copy

def age_processor():
    return make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(age_transformer),
)

total_relatives_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(sum_relatives)
)

cat_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
)

num_pipeline = make_pipeline([
        StandardScaler()
])

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
    ("ord", ord_pipeline, ['Pclass']),
    ("age_processing", age_processor(), ['Pclass', 'Age']),
    ("total_relatives", total_relatives_pipeline, ['SibSp', 'Parch']),
    ("cat", cat_pipeline, ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'traveling_category', 'age_interval']),
    ("num", num_pipeline, ['Fare']),
])
```

IT gives me the following error when calling the 'fit_transform' on my data:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[43], line 1
----> 1 data_processed = preprocessing.fit_transform(titanic_data)
      2 data_processed.shape

File ~/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py:    157, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
155 @wraps(f)
156 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 157     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
158     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
159         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
160         return_tuple = (
161             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
162             *data_to_wrap[1:],
163         )

File ~/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
...
445         "transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' "
446         "specifiers. '%s' (type %s) doesn't." % (t, type(t))
447     )

TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. 'Pipeline(steps=[('list', [('scaler', StandardScaler())])])' (type <class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>) doesn't.
```

I know that transformers given to the pipeline shouldn't be contained in a list but I have no idea why this error is being raised. Any help?

Comment: You are right, sorry for the hurry. Just fixed. Thanks for the touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is being caused by the square brackets in `make_pipeline()` for `num_pipeline`. Replace with:

```py
num_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler()
)
```

Alternatively, since it's just a single step, you could do the following if you wanted something a bit more concise:

```py
num_processor = StandardScaler()

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
    ...
    ("num", num_processor, ['Fare']),
])
```

If you are okay with skipping defining `num_processor`, you can supply `StandardScaler()` directly:

```py
preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
    ...
    ("num", StandardScaler(), ['Fare']),
])
```

Or to get both in a single line, the `:=` operator:

```py
preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
    ...
    ("num", num_processor := StandardScaler(), ['Fare']),
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Is see two problems in your code.

The first one: you pass the list of transformers to the [`make_pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html), however, it accepts the variable args as an input. So basically unwrap the list (from: `num_pipeline = make_pipeline([StandardScaler()])`, to `num_pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler())`.

The second problem is in:

```py
def age_transformer(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    for index, row in self.median_age_by_class.iterrows():
        class_value = row['Pclass']
        median_age = row['median_age']
        X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'] = X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'].fillna(median_age)
    bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    X_copy['age_interval'] = pd.cut(X_copy['Age'], bins=bins)
    return X_copy
```

You had it as a class before and there is leftover `self`. But it is a minor problem. The bigger is that you have a data leak. If you precomputed median age by class on the entire dataset, then you leak this information in this transformer.

The transformer should compute medians in fit, and then reuse these medians during the `transform` call. Why the data leak is a bad thing? Your algorithm sees data that shouldn't be seen and this will skew test results.

Comment: you are definitly right. About the 'self', yes, I noticed it a few moments after writing the question, but the other problem It really escaped me. But I am not sure about the "precoputed", I mean, when I call this pipeline is excatly after downloanding the data and separating it as a train and a test set. That is, I just download the data, split it and then call the pipeline to compute the median and fill the null values. Is there really a problem with this approach of leaking information?

Comment: In your use case, it is not a problem, because you are calculating the median on the training portion. However, the best practice is that the transformer should get that information from `fit` call. For example, let's say you want to do a cross-validation to assess the quality of the predictor. Then it splits your data into train-validation splits automatically, but each validation split has a data leak (as it has a global median). So in general it is better to compute statistics for training data inside the transformer `fit`, to avoid these gotchas.